# Kendo grid Horizontal Scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

How can i get and set Horizontal Scrollbar position o f a kendo grid?
If i do a setOptions(), the scrollbar wraps, but I want it to stay in the current position.

Comment: You want to stay on the current position? Why should it change? What are you doing that the position changes?

Comment: case you want to fixed a column so it will be visible when you user the horizontal scroll https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/frozen-columns